# Could not load file or assembly 'SharpSvn'

Tags: asp.net, .net, dll

I am using SharpSvn.dll and SharpSvnUI.dll in my project . I am getting error like this

> > Server Error in '/WebUI' Application.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'SharpSvn' or one of its dependencies.
>   An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'SharpSvn' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was
>   made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'SharpSvn' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Using :
VS 2015 -64bit

ref :
https://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/

Answer (score 1):

You will get this error if you try to host a web application using a 32 bit dll on a 64 bit server.Quick fix is to set "`Enable 32 bit applications`" flag to `true` in AppPool Advance Settings for the site.Select the Application Pool used for the application and the set that flag to true.Restart IIS.

[image: IIS]

Comment: Did the same , But not working and application pool stop when i try to open the url .. getting  "Service Unavailable


HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
"